# Вопросы вместо кириллицы в файле txt

Tags: windows

Здравствуйте,

В связи с неправильной установкой параметров в "языках и региональных стандартах" кириллица в файлах txt стала отображаться в виде "иероглифов". Изменив параметры, я смогла вернуть в нормальное состояние все файлы, кроме одного (с которым и работала и с которым больше всего экспериментировала, пытаясь вернуть к первоначальному виду): в нём теперь вместо "иероглифов" знаки вопроса.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли что-то с этим сделать, или уже нет. Заранее признательна!

Comment: Если Вы в какой-то момент сохранили его в кодировке ANSI, то - привет, восстанавливать там нечего.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте это:

Нажмите `Файл-Сохранить как` снизу вы увидите выбор кодировки, чтобы декодировать ваш текст обратно в кириллицу - сохраните его в формате `UTF-8`.

Comment: Спасибо большое за отклик! Увы, не подействовало.

Comment: Есть еще один способ: для этого вам понадобится программа Notepad++. 
Сверху, в панели, есть меню выбора кодировки, подробнее можно узнать по этой ссылке: http://mojwp.ru/faq/utf-8-bez-bom

Comment: К сожалению, и это не помогло. Спасибо за готовность помочь!

Comment: Вам пора бы уже понять, что восстанавливать уже там просто нечего -- о чём вам писали в комментарии к вопросу. На будущее: экспериментировать было либо на отдельном файле, либо после создания резервной копии.

Comment: Спасибо за крайне вежливый ответ.